# Swipable Tabs Framework7

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, html-framework-7

Im haveing some problem with swipable tabs. My issue is that Tab-2 is showing as activ when Tab-1 is set as active, and also there is some strange behavior when swiping and clicking the tabs.

I cant figuer out why this is happening! Anyone have any ideas, please feel free to help me.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2196f3">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap:">
    <title>Framework7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/f7-icon-square.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/f7-icon.png">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">        
        <div class="view view-main view-init">
            <div class="page hide-navbar-on-scroll">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
                        <div class="left">
                            <a href="#" class="link icon-only panel-open" data-panel="left">
                                <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">menu</i>
                                <i class="icon material-icons md-only">menu</i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="title sliding">Framework7</div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <a class="link icon-only searchbar-enable" data-searchbar=".searchbar-components">
                                <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">search_strong</i>
                                <i class="icon material-icons md-only">search</i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <form data-search-container=".components-list" data-search-in="a" class="searchbar searchbar-expandable searchbar-components searchbar-init">
                            <div class="searchbar-inner">
                                <div class="searchbar-input-wrap">
                                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search components"/>
                                    <i class="searchbar-icon"></i>
                                    <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                                <span class="searchbar-disable-button">Cancel</span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="toolbar tabbar tabbar-labels toolbar-bottom-md">
                    <div class="toolbar-inner">
                        <a href="#tab-1" class="tab-link tab-link-active">
                            <!-- Different icons for iOS and MD themes -->
                            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">email_fill</i>
                            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">email</i>
                            <!-- Label text -->
                            <span class="tabbar-label">Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#tab-2" class="tab-link">
                            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">today_fill<span class="badge color-red">5</span></i>
                            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">today<span class="badge color-red">5</span></i>
                            <span class="tabbar-label">Calendar</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#tab-3" class="tab-link">
                            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">cloud_fill</i>
                            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">file_upload</i>
                            <span class="tabbar-label">Upload</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>          
                <div class="tabs-swipeable-wrap">
                    <div class="tabs">
                        <div id="tab-1" class="page-content tab tab-active">
                            <div class="block">
                                <p>Tab 1 content</p>
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab-2" class="page-content tab">
                            <div class="block">
                                <p>Tab 2 content</p>
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab-3" class="page-content tab">
                            <div class="block">
                                <p>Tab 3 content</p>
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/framework7.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

[View of page when on Tab-1, but Tab-2 is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbYXn.png)

[And when clicking tab-2 then tab-3 is shwoing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB0kQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Searchbar is causing swipeable tabs to malfunction.

The solution is to disable searchbar-backdrop.

```
app.searchbar.create({
    el: '.searchbar',
    backdrop: false
});
```